# Control feature rendering order in QGIS with plugin

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-3

I am trying to find the python equivalent of enabling the checkbox for controlling the feature rendering order based on an attribute of the features of a layer (see below screenshot).

[image]

I want to base the rendering order on 'height' as shown in the screenshot.

My code below reads:

```
lyr_features = sorted(lyr_features, key = lambda i: i['height'])
colours = self.linear_gradient(len(lyr_features))
for i, feat in enumerate(lyr_features):
    myMin = feat['height']
    myMax = feat['height'] + 0.5
    myLabel = '{}'.format(feat['height'])
    myColour = QtGui.QColor(str(colours[i]))
    mySymbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(lyr.geometryType())
    mySymbol.setColor(myColour)
    mySymbol.setOpacity(myOpacity)
    myRange = QgsRendererRange(myMin, myMax, mySymbol, myLabel)
    myRangeList.append(myRange)

myRenderer = QgsGraduatedSymbolRenderer('', myRangeList)
myRenderer.setMode(QgsGraduatedSymbolRenderer.Pretty)
myStyle = QgsStyle().defaultStyle()
defaultColorRampNames = myStyle.colorRampNames()
ramp = myStyle.colorRamp(defaultColorRampNames[25])
myRenderer.setSourceColorRamp(ramp)
myRenderer.setClassAttribute(myTargetField)

lyr.setRenderer(myRenderer)
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(lyr)
lyr.triggerRepaint()
```

This is okay, but I then need to manually go in and enable the feature rendering control. Maybe something like this:

```
myRenderer.orderByEnabled(True)
```

This doesn't work but maybe along the lines of this?

Comment: That is not the correct method. You need to establish the order and then `setOrderByEnabled`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I add an example of code.

```
myRenderer.setOrderBy(QgsFeatureRequest.OrderBy([QgsFeatureRequest.OrderByClause('Value', False)]))
myRenderer.setOrderByEnabled(True)
```

QGIS Api [OrderByClause](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsFeatureRequest_1_1OrderByClause.html)

**OrderByClause (const QString &expression, bool ascending=true)**

Code reference : [QGIS Github](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/b3d2619976a69d7fb67b884492da491dfaba287c/tests/src/python/test_qgssinglesymbolrenderer.py#L69)