# Configure symbol levels using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, symbology, rendering, categorized-renderer

I have a `QgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer` and I'm trying to configure it so that `symbol_a`:

1. appears at the top of the layers window legend, but also
2. appears on top of all other `QgsRendererCategory` symbols (i.e. it should be rendered last).

In QGIS, I can do this by going to `Symbology > Advanced > Symbol Levels`, checking `Enable symbol levels` and configuring the `Layer 0` for `Label A` to `1`, leaving the others at `0`.

Using PyQGIS, I can enable symbol levels, but can't find a way to change the specific symbol levels (i.e. the order they are rendered).  Re-ordering the categories achieves this, but I'd prefer `Label A` to appear first in the layers window.  Is this possible?

My existing code looks something like this:

```
categories = [
    QgsRendererCategory('value_a', symbol_a, 'Label A'),
    QgsRendererCategory('value_b', symbol_b, 'Label B'),
    QgsRendererCategory('value_c', symbol_c, 'Label C'),
]

renderer = QgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer('field_name', categories)
renderer.setUsingSymbolLevels(True)
```

Comment: I'm trying the same thing and I'm afraid this functionality isn't available :  [QgsSymbolLevelsWidget](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsSymbolLevelsWidget.html)

Comment: Or maybe with [QgsSymbolLevelOrder](https://qgis.org/api/qgsrenderer_8h.html#a2aa4941a719aa94dd20bc9e1c70b78ba), but only in `QGIS3.17`

Answer (score 2):

This [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/322643/control-feature-rendering-order-in-qgis-with-plugin) give a good answer with a clause applied on the renderer :

```
myRenderer.setOrderBy(QgsFeatureRequest.OrderBy([QgsFeatureRequest.OrderByClause('Value', False)]))
myRenderer.setOrderByEnabled(True)
```

Edit: @simone100, to sort categories to specific levels, it's easier to work with symbol renderer categories. A full example could be (adapt `layer` and `symbol` if necessary):

```
# Define the layer
layer = iface.activeLayer()

# Field for classification
expression = 'CLASSE'

# Symbol
symbol = QgsFillSymbol.defaultSymbol(layer.geometryType())

# Categorized styles: declared order will be the same in the tree view
categories = [    
    QgsRendererCategory('S2', symbol, 'S2'),
    QgsRendererCategory('S3', symbol, 'S3'),
    QgsRendererCategory('S1', symbol, 'S1')
]

renderer = QgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer(expression, categories)
        
# Apply style to layer
layer.setRenderer(renderer)
        
# Refresh layer's symbology
iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(layer.id())
```

Comment: QgsFeatureRequest (expression: str, ascending: bool = True). You insert 'Value'  and I assume that is the field name. Your answer don't tell how to insert the expression if you want to sort the attributes specifically for the levels. For example I have a field "Water" that has 3 attributes ('S1', 'S2', S3'). How can you insert in the expression by telling for S1 level 1, for S2 level 3, for S3 level 2? I assume you have to modify the part "OrderByClause('Value', False)" in something like "OrderByClause('CASE WHEN 'Water'='S1' THEN 1' and so on. But I don't know how to do.

Comment: [Documentation](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsFeatureRequest_1_1OrderByClause.html) says that clause could be an field or an expression. Have you tried `QGIS` expressions like `CASE` or `IF` syntax ?

Comment: I did with the field 'CLASSE' but it does not work. 
expression = "CASE WHEN "CLASSE" is 'S1' THEN '3' END; CASE WHEN "CLASSE" is 'S2' THEN '2' END'; CASE WHEN "CLASSE" is 'S2' THEN '2' END' "

Comment: renderer = QgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer("CLASSE", list)
renderer.setUsingSymbolLevels(True)
expression = QgsExpression("CASE WHEN 'CLASSE' is 'S1' THEN '3' END")
renderer.setOrderBy(QgsFeatureRequest.OrderBy([QgsFeatureRequest.OrderByClause(expression, False)]))
renderer.setOrderByEnabled(True) in this case renderer is enabled for level (so it works something!), there is no error but the layer level remains S1=0 and not S1=3   @GeoGyro

Comment: Syntax matters, try: `CASE WHEN "CLASSE" = 'S1' THEN '3' WHEN "CLASSE" = 'S2' THEN '2' WHEN "CLASSE" = 'S2' THEN '2' END`

Comment: this is the right syntax: expression = QgsExpression("CASE WHEN 'CLASSE' is 'S1' THEN '3' END; CASE WHEN 'CLASSE' is 'S2' THEN '2' END ") When I did there is no error. Nevertheless, the simbols layer remains all to default with value 0! The level in the vector become enable, but unfortunately there is no change on the value 0!

Comment: renderer.setOrderByEnabled(True) and renderer.setUsingSymbolLevels(True) run good, the other does not run for me even if there is no error!

Comment: See my edit in my answer

Comment: I have create a post with the question. You can see my problem. 
https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/449940/165037
@GeoGyro