# Setting symbol level to the symbols with pyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, symbology, categorized-renderer

I am able to apply a style to a vector called "merged_zone".

Here my script:

```
# Symbol
sym1 = QgsFillSymbol.createSimple({'color': '#bed2ff', 'outline_color': 'black'})
sym2 = QgsFillSymbol.createSimple({'color': '#bee8ff', 'outline_color': 'black'})
sym3 = QgsFillSymbol.createSimple({'color': '#beffe8', 'outline_color': 'black'})

# Categorized styles: declared order will be the same in the tree view
categories = [
    QgsRendererCategory('S1', sym1, 'S1'),
    QgsRendererCategory('S2', sym2, 'S2'),
    QgsRendererCategory('S3', sym3, 'S3')
]

renderer = QgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer('CLASSE', categories)
        
# Apply style to layer
merged_zone.setRenderer(renderer)
merged_zone.triggerRepaint()
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(merged_zone)
```

The result is this:

[image]

With this legend:
[image]

With this result am happy for the colors symbol, legend and so on.

But I wnat also to have symbol levels, and for that I am unhappy:
with the abovementioned code they are not enabled and the layer() has no value

[image]

I try to follow what @GeoGyro told in https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/378373/165037

He suggested this code:

```
myRenderer.setOrderBy(QgsFeatureRequest.OrderBy([QgsFeatureRequest.OrderByClause('Value', False)]))
myRenderer.setOrderByEnabled(True)
```

So, I integrate the code that he suggested into mine with an expression:

```
# Symbol
sym1 = QgsFillSymbol.createSimple({'color': '#bed2ff', 'outline_color': 'black'})
sym2 = QgsFillSymbol.createSimple({'color': '#bee8ff', 'outline_color': 'black'})
sym3 = QgsFillSymbol.createSimple({'color': '#beffe8', 'outline_color': 'black'})

# Categorized styles: declared order will be the same in the tree view
categories = [
    QgsRendererCategory('S1', sym1, 'S1'),
    QgsRendererCategory('S2', sym2, 'S2'),
    QgsRendererCategory('S3', sym3, 'S3')
]

renderer = QgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer('CLASSE', categories)
        
# Apply style to layer
merged_zone.setRenderer(renderer)
renderer.setUsingSymbolLevels(True)
expression = QgsExpression("CASE WHEN 'CLASSE' is 'S1' THEN '3' END; CASE WHEN 'CLASSE' is 'S2' THEN '2' END; CASE WHEN 'CLASSE' is 'S3' THEN '1' END ")
renderer.setOrderBy(QgsFeatureRequest.OrderBy([QgsFeatureRequest.OrderByClause(expression, False)]))
renderer.setOrderByEnabled(True)
merged_zone.triggerRepaint()
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(merged_zone)
```

There is no error when I run my last code. The symbol levels are enabled (good!), but unfortunately the layers() are still ALL 0 even if in the expression I told to put S1=3, S2= 2, S3=1! The image of the zones are unchanged in comparison with the first rendering.

[image]

This is an image of the result that I would like to have. I setted manually in QGIS to show you:
[image]

If you look at the image above the zone S2 is upper S3, S2 always hides S3. With my code, even with the last one, unfortunately does not happen.

Comment: I guess that could be a problem of syntax. expression = QgsExpression("CASE WHEN 'CLASSE' is 'S1' THEN '3' END; CASE WHEN 'CLASSE' is 'S2' THEN '2' END; CASE WHEN 'CLASSE' is 'S3' THEN '1' END ") could be wrong. I experienced a similar issue before in a less long expression. It does not give an error, but it does not apply to the symbol what I wanted. I am not able to see where there is the problem that makes the expression not good to pass to QGIS.