# PyQGIS categorized symbol renderer sort by label

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I wan't to sort a `QGIS` categorized symbol renderer by label name with `PyQGIS`. First i create categories and after i apply them to my layer but how to make an ascending alphabetic order on categorie's name ?

Documentation explain we can sort categories by their label with [.sortByLabel()](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer.html#qgis.core.QgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer.sortByLabel).

I'm using `QGIS3.10.2`.

```
# Categories
categories = []
for myAttrName, (color, label, contour) in myStyleDict.items():
    symbol = QgsFillSymbol.defaultSymbol(myLayer.geometryType())
    symbol.setColor(QColor(color))
    symbol.symbolLayer(0).setStrokeWidth(0.26)
    symbol.symbolLayer(0).setStrokeColor(QColor(contour))
    category = QgsRendererCategory(myAttrName, symbol, label)
    categories.append(category)

# Renderer
expression = 'myAttrField'
renderer = QgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer(expression, categories) 
#renderer = QgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer(expression, categories).sortByLabel() ?  
myLayer.setRenderer(renderer)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/322643/control-feature-rendering-order-in-qgis-with-plugin) give a good answer with a clause applied on the renderer. To complete my previous post, I add this after the `.setRenderer` :

```
renderer.setOrderBy(QgsFeatureRequest.OrderBy([QgsFeatureRequest.OrderByClause(expression, False)]))
renderer.setOrderByEnabled(True)
```